# Setting control text in parent form from modal popup

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, modalpopupextender

I have a problem I am trying to set the parent textbox  from the modal popup.

Although I found the control from the modal popup with the below code
`DirectCast(Parent.Page.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("myAccordion").FindControl("txtTo"), TextBox).Text = str`

This is being called on button click when the user has finished selecting from the Checkboxlist.

When the parent page is shown again though the textbox is empty.

The scenario of my user control is that a user is to select from a checkbox list which is a list of emails.

When done has been clicked then it is required that the selected emails be forwarded to the parent webpage.

Then the To Textbox in this case will be filled with the emails that the user has selected.

Comment: Where is your ModalPopupExtender located and where do you need to access the textbox?

Comment: It is in a user control and the parent of the user control will be where the textbox is located

Comment: So you have a CheckBoxList `SelectedIndexChanged` event in your usercontrol, want to close the control and inform the "opener" that a value was selected which must be shown in a TextBox in that page? What kind of information is shown in the TextBox? (asking to provide a meaningful answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide a public property in your `UserControl` for the selected item in the `ListBox`. This makes it easy to retrieve(or set) it from the page.

You should also declare an event that you can raise from the ListBox' `SelectedIndexChanged` event. On this way the page is able to handle this event and set the TextBox' Text accordingly.

For example(in UserControl with `ModalPopupExtender`):

```
Public Class PopupControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Event ItemChanged(ByVal popup As PopupControl)

    Public Property SelectedItem As String

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
        Dim lb = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
        Me.Visible = False

        Me.SelectedItem = lb.SelectedItem.ToString()
        RaiseEvent ItemChanged(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

In page:

```
Protected Sub PopupItemChanged(ByVal popup As PopupControl)Handles PopupControl1.ItemChanged
    Me.txtTo.Text = popup.SelectedItem
End Sub
```

Comment: @Enzero: Where is your page's Textbox located? Is it in any kind of databound control(like FormView) that you are rebinding from database on postbacks(f.e. in Page_Load)? Is it in an UpdatePanel? Then you could try to set it's UpdateMode to `Conditional` and call `UpdatePanel.Update()` from codebehind after you changed the Text.

Comment: The textbox is in an accordion as can be seen when i first asked the question.

Comment: I've never used Accordion since it blows the ViewState and has [some painful characteristics](http://couldbedone.blogspot.fr/2007/07/what-wrong-with-accordion-control.html). Try to add `Accordion1.FindControl("nothing");` in your Page_Init. You also might want to have a look here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1115188/1726464.aspx

Comment: The update-panel seems to have finally done it. I had to set it to update always since i didn't think that adding a button would be sensible.Thanks